# What does "Supports ECC UDIMM memory (non-ECC mode)" mean?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ecc

According to [MSI, the motherboard I'm looking at](https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/mb/MAGB550MMORTARWIFI_MAGB550MMORTAR.pdf)

> Supports ECC UDIMM memory (non-ECC mode)

What does this mean even?

Comment: its telling you you can use ECC ram, but the ECC feature will not function. so you can use a wider variety of RAM chips, but you won't be able to actually use ECC as a feature. it will just work as normal non-ECC ram.

Comment: @Frank So basically, it doesn't support ECC.. I'll accept that answer. That's what I thought. What's the purpose of paying for a premium ram that runs slower then non-ecc just to have it no provide the error protection?

Comment: Mobo manufacturers are all about supporting as many acronyms as possible at any given time. guess it was ecc's turn.

Comment: The ECC memory modules seem to be a better quality, so even without implementing the error detection and handling, the system might be more reliable with them. It is difficult to find statistics, but e.g. here they experienced more than 2-4 times lower failure rate: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/advantages-of-ecc-memory-520/#ECC_Failure_Rate_Analysis